# How to refresh only one section of list in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have complex `RecyclerView` where I'm using adapter with 5 `ViewHolders`. I created custom sections similar to Contact list. But in my recyclerView, items from one section can reset everything inside other section. But I don't know how to do it.

What I'm doing now is wiping whole adapter list and adding items again, which is not efficient way to do this. 
Also items inside `Section 1` contain CheckBox, which if checked, it can wipe out all data in `Section 2` and `Section 3`.

`OnCheckedChangeListener` and setting of `CheckBox` state from `itemList[pos]` state are set inside `onBindViewHolder` (checking default checked item inside section at start of binding). If checked is set on true, it will refresh whole list and call `notifyDataSetChanged`. **That is made because all other items in different sections are based on checked item in first section.**

This is causing crashes because of `concurrent modification exception`. Everytime as one of those items are binded again inside `onBindViewHolder` checked change listener is fired and whole list is refreshed. If this is called 2 or more times in a row, it will crash my app.
Also if user will scroll up and down and Section1 items starts reappearing and disappearing it will call onBindViewHolder multiple times in a row => notifyDataSetChanged() is called multiple times => exception.

Android `RecyclerView` really lacks native support for sections. It would be really cool to just set sections at start like subArrays and then call `adapter.updateSection(1)` for example.

This would also be better if I could make separate `RecyclerView`for each section, but this whole RecyclerView has to be scrollable. Adding 4 `RecyclerViews` inside `NestedScrollView` will kill recycling mechanism.

A code preview for refreshing items:

```
val selectedVariantFirstSectionJSONObject = getSelectedVariantInJSON(selectedVariantID)
        ingredientsItemList.apply {
            clear()
            add(IngredientHeaderItemNonIconified(getString(R.string.food_ingredients_variant_label)))
            addAll(foodVariantsArray)
            add(IngredientSectionSeparator())
            add(IngredientHeaderItemNonIconified(getString(R.string.food_ingredients_required_ingredients_label)))
            add(RequiredIngredient(getVariantRequiredIngredients(selectedVariantJSONObject.getJSONArray(getString(R.string.food_variant_required_ingredients)))))
            add(IngredientSectionSeparator())
            add(IngredientHeaderItemIconified(getString(R.string.food_ingredients_remove_ingredients_label), TYPE_INGREDIENT_REM))
            addAll(removableIngredients)
            add(IngredientSectionSeparator())
            add(IngredientHeaderItemIconified(getString(R.string.food_ingredients_add_ingredients_label), TYPE_INGREDIENT_OPT))
            addAll(optionalIngredients)
        }

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Image for better understanding(its a bit complex):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply call `RvAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(start,count);` 
and same thing for sub adapters if you have

Answer (score 0):

If you have the modified item positions, then just pass those, 
run the following method in a loop of the list which has positions of modified data.

```
 public void updateItem(Data Data, int position) {
        mDataList.add(position, data);
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
```